# MX Title Control + Structure

Tags: structure, url-title, title, mx-title-control

I'm using MX Title Control to concatenate two entry fields into the entry title. This is working correctly for the URL Title value as well. However, my Structure Listing URL looks like `auto_replace-97`.

Has anyone gotten MX Title Control working with Structure URLs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [Title Master](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/title-master) is claiming full Structure support and Title Control is not, so I'll be moving in that direction.