# auto_replace-### in Wygwam field

Tags: wygwam, structure, links, title-master

My client has created a link to an entry within a Wygwam field, and we also have a link to the same entry as a Playa/relationship link.

The Playa/relationship link is working fine. In the Wygwam field, we see:

```
http://staging.domain.com/reference-item/auto_replace-100
```

I suspect I know what's going on, that something changed with this entry and the Wygwam field wasn't updated. I've looked in the Source view, and that's the value stored there as well.

What's the best way to correct this? Just update such links in the Wygwam field? Or is there a better way to cover this?

We're also using Title Master to generate URL Titles from a few different fields in the entry being referenced. An update may have broken something on that end. I'm aware of a few issues on that front that we need to work through as well.

(May be related to [MX Title Control + Structure](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/q/6958/293))

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've been having a similar issue for several months with Title Master and haven't been able to get any assistance from the developer. I eventually had to abandon using a "url title" that was composed of multiple components and do something a little more old fashioned.

Comment: Good to know. He took a look at an issue I was having a while back and sent me a patch that fixed it on new entries, but left old ones broken. Might have to ditch it for URL support and retain it for just the titles. Thanks!